# jQuery ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm trying to get started with jQuery UI tabs.
Right now it's not working.
I thought I'd use the Google version so that it would be cached.
I'd like to find where Google has ui.tabs.js as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css">
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.load("jqueryui", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {  
    $("#myTabs").tabs();
});  
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="myTabs">
    <li><a href="#0"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#1"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="0">This is the content panel linked to the first tab, it is shown by default.</div>
<div id="1">This content is linked to the second tab and will be shown when its tab is clicked.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose all the tabs in the same continer:

```
<div id="myTabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#0"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#1"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="0">This is the content panel linked to the first tab, it is shown by default.</div>
<div id="1">This content is linked to the second tab and will be shown when its tab is clicked.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh that was it!  That's not a good sign, because this was example #1 in the jQuery UI 1.6 book!